# UNIQUE formula + IF

Tags: google-sheets, filter, unique, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

Looking to combine google sheet unique formula with an If formula. See below. The outcome should be Unique values from column "B" and only active values from column "C".

```
Column B.      Column C
Sweden         Active
Sweden         Active
Spain          Inactive
Denmark        Inactive
England        Active
England        Active
```

Preferred outcome

```
Sweden
England
```

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
=UNIQUE(QUERY(B:C, "select B where C = 'Active'", 0))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(B:B,C:C="Active"))
```

[image]

Comment: @bertathaman please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
=QUERY(UNIQUE(D16:E21),"Select Col1 where Col2='Active'")
```

Comment: *Try* is not an answer. You must be sure in your answer. *Try* should be in comments.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24925107)

Comment: Althought this give the result as hope but different row, I accept your review. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use filter. Sample Usage:

FILTER(A2:B26, A2:A26 > 5, D2:D26 < 10)

FILTER(A2:C5, {TRUE; TRUE; FALSE; TRUE})

FILTER(A2:B10, NOT(ISBLANK(A2:A10)))

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en